# android project build successful,but can not run at virtual device

Tags: android, build

when i build my android project use Android Studio, it shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL, But when i run at my virtual Device , it shows error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
  >   index (0) must be less than size (0)
  >   Must apply 'com.android.application' first!

My Android Studio Version is V2.2.3, my virtual device is Nexus 5 API 24

Answer (score 0):

update your **Android Gradle Plugin** in **build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}
```